# Getting rid of full index scan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

The following query performs badly because of a full non-clustered index scan of 6.5 million records in P4FileReleases followed by a hash join.  I'm looking for possible reasons the optimizer picks a scan over a seek.

```
SELECT p4f.FileReleaseID 
   FROM P4FileReleases p4f
   INNER JOIN AnalyzedFileView af 
      ON p4f.FileRelease = (af.path+'#'+cast(af.revision as varchar))  
   WHERE (af.tracked_change_id = 1)
```

From what I can tell, I see no reason for the optimizer to pick a scan of P4FileReleases.  The WHERE clause limits the size of the right dataset to about 1K of records and the optimizer should know it (see the histogram below).

If fact, if I take the view data and throw it into a heap table (same structure as the indexed view), then the query is performed with an index seek on the larger table and an inner join loop instead of a hash join (and the total cost drops from 145 to around 1).

Any ideas on what might be throwing the optimizer off?

**Details.**  Sql Server 2008 (v. 10.0.2757.0).

**P4FileReleases table**
Holds 6.5 million records

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[P4FileReleases](
    [FileReleaseID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FileRelease] [varchar](254) NOT NULL,
    -- 5 more fields 
 CONSTRAINT [CIX_P4FileReleases_FileReleaseID_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FileReleaseID] ASC
),
CONSTRAINT [NCIX_P4FileReleases_FileRelease] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [FileRelease] ASC
)
```

**AnalyzedFileView**
is an indexed view with statistics enabled and up-to-date.

It has four columns:

```
   key int (int, PK) - clustered index
   tracked_change_id (int, FK) - non-unique, non-clustered index (covering 'path', 'revision')
   path (nvarchar(1024), null) 
   revision (smallint, null)
```

tracked_change_id histogram:

```
1   0   1222    0   1
4   0   787     0   1
8   0   2754    0   1
12  0   254     0   1
13  0   34      0   1
```

**Query Plan**

```
  |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
       |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([Expr1011])=([Expr1010]), RESIDUAL:([Expr1010]=[Expr1011]))
            |--Bitmap(HASH:([Expr1011]), DEFINE:([Bitmap1015]))
            |    |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Expr1011]))
            |         |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1011]=([qpsitools].[dbo].[analyzed_file_view].[path]+N'#')+CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(30),CONVERT(varchar(30),[qpsitools].[dbo].[analyzed_file_view].[revision],0),0)))
            |              |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([qpsitools].[dbo].[analyzed_file_view].[tracked_change_id]), SEEK:([qpsitools].[dbo].[analyzed_file_view].[tracked_change_id]=(1)) ORDERED FORWARD)
            |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([Expr1010]), WHERE:(PROBE([Bitmap1015],[Expr1010])))
                 |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1010]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(254),[Blueprint].[dbo].[P4FileReleases].[FileRelease] as [p4f].[FileRelease],0)))
                      |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([Blueprint].[dbo].[P4FileReleases].[NCIX_P4FileReleases_FileRelease] AS [p4f]))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are joining varchar column p4f.FileRelease with an nvarchar column (af.path). Since the data types don't match, SQL has to convert one's type to the other's (and of course it can't go from nvarchar to varchar). In converting af.path to nvarchar, it loses the ability to use the index to lookup/filter those values, resulting in the need to scan and convert all possible rows.

The best solution is to store the data as matching data types (change column p4f.FileRelase to nvarchar, or af.path to varchar). Since no one ever gets to modify existing database structures, a work-around might be to explicitly cast af.path to varchar in the query. Test it and see... though of course you can't do this if the data truly requires double-byte formatting.

Comment: Even if it was stored as matching types the fact that he is concating two fields with a # inbetween will force a scan won't it?

Comment: Awesome!  Looks like varchar vs nvarchar was the problem.  thanks!

Comment: @Mike M, there is little difference *to SQL* between "...WHERE ColName = @Variable" and "...WHERE ColName = @Variable + @Variable". It takes whatever value you've generated, and looks it up in the table.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is not the WHERE but the JOIN, you are getting an implicit conversion and a scan on the JOIN, on the WHERE condition you are getting a SEEK

```
ON p4f.FileRelease = (af.path+'#'+cast(af.revision as varchar))
```

Parallelism could also be a problem, try adding MAXDOP=1

Are your statistics up to date? Is there excessive fragmentation?

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm saying: i'm getting a seek on the where and a scan on the join.  And I'd like to understand why.  I actually am using MAXDOP=1, I just omitted it here.  So all the data I've included is for non-parallel processing.

Comment: the optimizer doesn't know whet the value of af.path+'#'+cast(af.revision as varchar) is so it has to scan the whole table

Answer (score 0):

Try moving "af.tracked_change_id = 1" into the join clause.

```
INNER JOIN AnalyzedFileView af 
ON p4f.FileRelease = (af.path+'#'+cast(af.revision as varchar))
AND af.tracked_change_id = 1
```

WHERE is applied after the INNER JOIN

Comment: Doing so had no affect.  Shouldn't the optimizer be smart enough to make rearrangements like that automatically anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Philip Kelley spotted the problem.  It was a datatype mismatch between varchar in P4FileReleases and nvarchar in AnalyzedFileView.